# How to reuse outer wrapping iteration code in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, reusability, readability

I would like to reuse same iteration code multiple times and I want to define it just once.
Within the iteration there can be various different methods with various different inputs. How can this be done in C#?

I am not concerned with performance. My main concern is "**not repeating the same code**" and **readability**.

See following pseudo-code. I would like to replace `DoMainStuff()` with something that would look like `DoMainStuff_Desired()`.

(I was so far trying to solve it with delegates.It reduced readability a lot. See second attached code.)

```
public class Class1
{
    public void DoStuff1(int x,int y)
    {
        //Doing something.
    }

    public void DoStuff2(int x, int y, string bla)
    {
        //Doing something.
    }

    public void DoStuffx(int x, int y, "whatevertype" ble, "maybe more inputs")
    {
        //This represents multiple methods that do stuff.
        //They can have different number of inputs of different types.
        //I do not know all of them at this point.
    }

    public void DoMainStuff()
    {
        //I do not want to repeat same code for iteration multiple times.

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                DoStuff1(x, y);
            }

        }

        //Something happening that prevents me having it in the same loop.


        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                DoStuff2(x, y, "somestring");
            }

        }

        //Something happening that prevents me having it in the same loop.

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                DoStuffx(x, y, "somestring", 50f, "anotherstring"); 
            }

        }

    }

    public void DoMainStuff_Desired()
    {
        //This is how I want to have it. (Something similar)

        WrappedInIteration(DoStuff1(x, y));
        //Something happening that prevents me having it in the same loop.
        WrappedInIteration(DoStuff2(x, y, "somestring"));
        //Something happening that prevents me having it in the same loop.
        WrappedInIteration(DoStuffx(x, y, "somestring", 50f, "anotherstring"));

    }

}
```

Here is what I have tried with delegate. I do not like this solution, because I had to modify DoStuffx methods to have the same argument signature as the delegate. (params object[] args) -> this signature allows whatever inputs, but it makes it hard to read, because it is not obvious what inputs are actually needed for various different DoStuffx methods.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void DoStuff1(params object[] args)
    {
        //Doing something.
    }

    public void DoStuff2(params object[] args)
    {
        //Doing something.
    }

    public void DoStuffx(params object[] args)
    {
        //This represents multiple methods that do stuff.
        //They can have different number of inputs of different types.
        //I do not know all of them at this point.
    }

    public void DoMainStuff()
    {
        WrappedInIteration_DelegateVersion(DoStuff1);
        //Something happening that prevents me having it in the same loop.
        WrappedInIteration_DelegateVersion(DoStuff2, "somestring");
        //Something happening that prevents me having it in the same loop.
        WrappedInIteration_DelegateVersion(DoStuffx, "somestring", 50f, "anotherstring");

    }



    public delegate void DelegateForDoStuff(params object[] args);

    public void WrappedInIteration_DelegateVersion(DelegateForDoStuff DoStuff, params object[] args)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                DoStuff(x,y, args);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There are _lots_ of possible ways to refactor code like this. Your question is too broad. Please fix the question so that it shows what you actually tried, explains why your attempt did not solve your problem, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried to address your points. I would be grateful if you could just point me in the direction of some of the "lots of possible ways to refactor code like this".